# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n < \infty \Rightarrow \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I'd like to check if my proof works. I'm not quite sure if it is clear enough.

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. I'm trying to prove the following claim:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n < \infty \Rightarrow \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n \rightarrow 0.$$

Here is the main idea:

If the series is convergent, than it is a Cauchy sequence. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon>0$, $\exists M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m_0,m_1\geq M$ (suppose $m_0\geq m_1$) we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^{m_0}x_n - \sum_{n=1}^{m_1}x_n < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \sum_{n=m_1+1}^{m_0}x_n<\varepsilon.$$

The proof goes along these lines:

Considere the sequence $\left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n, \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}x_n, \sum_{n=3}^{\infty}x_n, \dots, \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n, \dots \right)$. Lets prove that it converges to $0$. With the reasoning above, it should be clear that there exists a $n_0=m_1+1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N\geq n_0 \Rightarrow \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n <\varepsilon$.

I'd like to justify this argument by saying that $\infty > m_0$, thus, the inequality above is true. It seems logical but I'm aware that thing get tricky with infinity and I'm not comfortable with swapping thing around without a proper explanation. Is the proof correct? Is there a better way to write this down?

Comment: If you are assuming that $\sum_{n>N} x_n$ is Cauchy, then you are begging the question: assuming what you're supposed to be proving.

Comment: Could you explain further? I was using a lecture note theorem (convergence $\Rightarrow$ cauchy) and interpreting the series $\sum_{n>1}x_n$ as the sequence ($x_1$, $x_1+x_2$, $x_1+x_2+x_3$,$\dots$). I figured out that this sequence should be Cauchy (not $\sum_{n>n}x_n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this (so everything is expressed in finite sums and we just use very simple properties of limits of sequences) : let $t_{Nm}=\sum_{n=0}^{m}x_{n+N}$ the partial sums of the series $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n$ and $t_{0m}=s_m=\sum_{n=0}^mx_n$ the partial sums of the original series and $s=\lim s_m$ the sum of the original series

Then for fixed $N \ge 1$ we have $t_{Nm}=s_{m+N}-s_{N-1} \to s-s_{N-1}, m \to \infty$ since $s_{m+N} \to s$ as $m \to \infty$ by hypothesis.

Hence if we call $t_N=s-s_{N-1}$ then $t_N=\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}x_n$ by the defintion of a sum of a series.

However since $s_{N-1} \to s, N \to \infty$ again by hypothesis, it follows that $t_N \to s-s=0$ as $N \to \infty$ so we are done!